# Массовая загрузка невозможна. Файл «C:\Users\as11\Desktop\C#_Projekte\rechnung.csv» не существует или у вас нет прав доступа к файлу. - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Массовая загрузка невозможна. Файл «C:\Users\as11\Desktop\C#_Projekte\rechnung.csv» не существует или у вас нет прав доступа к файлу. - SQL Server. Не пойму почему так происходит.

```
BULK INSERT CSV
FROM 'C:\Users\as11\Desktop\C#_Projekte\rechnung.csv'
WITH (
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIRSTROW = 3,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Может кто то может подсказать...
Разделитель в моем случае ';'

Comment: У SQL Server свой пользователь, ему права на файл нужны

Comment: Спасибо. Где их добавляют?

Comment: В файловой системе той ОС, в которой работает SQL Server.

Comment: OK. ясно. Спасибо